# Find the optimal position minimising the total path cost to multiple goals (A-star without a starting position?)

Tags: path-finding

I have a 2D grid of discrete tiles, where some tiles (W) are impassable. Given a number of goals (G), what is the best way to find the position that minimises the total cost to all the goals?

Example:

```
.......G..
.WWW......
..GW......
...W....W.
.WWW....W.
........WG
```

I'm familiar with Djikstra and A-star, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this problem, or whether I should be using something else entirely.

The dumb brute force option here is to create a complete cost matrix for every goal, sum these to create a total cost matrix and then find the node or nodes with the lowest total cost. This would work fine, but I'm sure this could be done more efficiently using some sort of directed search.

Comment: The sum of the distances would give you the total distance to hit all goals, if each time you reach a goal you immediately teleport back to the start point. Is that what you want, or do you need the shortest Hamiltonian path that reaches its first goal then navigates from its first goal to its second, etc?

Comment: I'm not looking for a distance or a path. I'm looking for the point that minimises the total distance to all the goals. Think of the goals as static resources that I will be travelling to often. I want to decide where to build my base to minimise the travelling time in the future.

Comment: Your "dumb brute force option" is what I was going to suggest. It should be O(numNodes*numGoals). It'd be surprising to me if there were anything faster than that.

Comment: It is possible to batch-together the G breadth-first search invocations into one breadth-first search with G starting points, sharing some.work in the overlaps, but I'm not sure it saves anything worthwhile when weighed against the extra complexity it adds to the code.